# Is there any way to silence the 'hold' function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm doing some data analysis in Matlab, and anytime I call the hold function to keep plotting to the current figure, I get an output like this:

```
Current plot held
```

I'd like to avoid this print, since it's just ugly and clutters my output. Unfortunately, placing a ; after the command does not silence it.

Is there something I can do (save from reworking my display code to avoid 'hold' commands altogether)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like the hold command displays "Current plot held" if you call it with the axis handle as the sole parameter, e.g.

```
>> hold(gca)
Current plot released
>> hold(gca)
Current plot held
```

However, if you tell it the hold state you want then the output is suppressed, e.g.,

```
>> hold(gca,'on')
>>
```

You could also call hold in the following manner

```
>> axes(axesHandle)
>> hold on % or hold('on') if you prefer calling it as a function
```

If you want to avoid using the hold command/function, you could set the *NextPlot* property of the axis to *add*, e.g.

```
>> axesHandle=axes;
>> set(axesHandle,'NextPlot','add')
```