# MATLAB - Plot multiple data sets on a scatter plot

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I have two sets of data, (Ax, Ay; Bx, By). I'd like to plot both of these data sets on a scatter plot with different colors, but I can't seem to get it to work, because it seems `scatter()` does not work like `plot()`. Is it possible to do this?

I've tried...

```
scatter(Ax, Ay, 'g', Bx, By, 'b')
```

And

```
scatter(Ax, Ay, 'g')
scatter(Bx, By, 'b')
```

The first way returns an error. The latter only plots the `Bx`/`By` data.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386712/is-there-any-way-to-silence-the-hold-function-in-matlab/386765#386765

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try using `hold on` with the second example.

Comment: That did the trick! Many thanks for the speedy and concise response. Much appreciated!

Comment: This may cause some headache if you are trying to combine it with adding legends. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33059911/478116).

Comment: This is fine, but you are not able to plot all best fitting lines at once.

Answer (score 6):

> plot (ax,ay,'g.') 
>   generates a scatter plot with green dots

if you want bigger circles, you can use

> plot (ax,ay,'g.', 'MarkerSize', XX) %XX = 20 or whatever

To make open circles

> plot (ax, ay, 'go')

As you know, plot can be chained, so you can do it one go with

> plot (ax, ay, 'go', bx, by, 'bo')

The difference between plot and scatter is that scatter lets you specify the marker size, but you're not asking to do that here.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use gscatter. The parameters are different, but it is sometimes more useful than `scatter(...); hold on; scatter(...);`