# Overlaying / Plotting on top of an existing plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I have a heat map of values generated by "pcolor" in MATLAB. I would like to plot a line plot on top of that.

I haven't found a proper solution in any measure yet.

The following code generates a "heat map" sort of output

```
 hc = pcolor(middle_long, middle_height, middle_no2);
 set(hc, 'Edgecolor', 'none');
 c = colorbar;
 caxis([0 0.015]);
 axis([min(middle_long(:,1)) max(middle_long(:,1)) 0 1000])
```

The following code generates a line plot

```
 plot(longflag, hflag)
```

The following are figures of the individual plot types that I would like to join, with an "example" of the final product I'd like listed afterwards:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this? `pcolor(rand(10)), colormap bone, axis xy, hold on, plot([1 10], [10 1], 'r')` Are you missing `hold on` perhaps?

Comment: @LuisMendo Holy cow, yep, that worked! Thank you for the help! I'm new to stack. Can I give you a "check mark" on here somehow?

Comment: Glad it worked. I’ll post it as an answer tomorrow, so you can mark it as accepted

Comment: Maybe a better dupe target?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481688/matlab-plot-multiple-data-sets-on-a-scatter-plot

Comment: @CrisLuengo I included both. Thanks! I knew there had to be a dupe but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Note the `hold on` part, which prevents `plot` from deleting the image produced by `pcolor`:

```
pcolor(rand(10))
colormap bone
axis xy
hold on
plot([1 10], [10 1], 'r')
```

[image]